# Define virtual hosts on Azure Linux

Tags: virtualhost, httpd, ubuntu-14.04

I am using Azure Linux (Ubuntu 14.04) and I need to define two VirtualHost as per below. However, I cannot see any httpd folders. Where can I do it?

```
<VirtualHost app1.example.com:80>
    ServerName app1.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/sites/app1
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    <Proxy *>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3000/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost app2.example.com:80>
    ServerName app2.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/sites/app2
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    <Proxy *>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3000/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Put those virtual hosts inside /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ubuntu 14.04, The location of Apache configuration files is under /etc/apache2/

Put those virtual hosts inside the file called /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default & the reload the configuration.

Comment: Are you able to find the configuration files under /etc/apache2/ ?

Comment: I just checked and there is no /etc/apache2 directory. When I ssh and get the config I can see: Distributor ID: Ubuntu Description: Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS Release: 14.04 Codename: trusty

Comment: You need to install apache web server by using this command -> sudo apt-get install apache2

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't retain my changes.